# ssis handling referential integrity checks and errors

Tags: ssis

How do you guys handle referential integrity checks in SSIS to mapping tables.  Currently I do a lookup early on in the process and redirect non matches to an error table. Is this the best way?  Ive done other packages where ive checked for errors when dumping data into a table but it seems if your using fastload then if there is an error the whole batch gets redirected.

Is there a better way or am i doing this correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three ways to check for referential integrity in SSIS:

- in source query (if you can do a proper join in source query)
- using some component (lookup, join/merge, script task)
- let the destination report an error

As You already said, fastload destination redirects whole batch to the error output. If You expect referential integrity problem to occur rarely, You might want to:

1. redirect error rows to another destination to the same table but set the destination to write in batches of 1 row
2. then redirect error rows from this new destination to the error table

This should work fine if your destination batch size is not too big, otherwise, this solution might be slow for You. Also, You might want to consider turning off Check Constraints or disabling foreign keys before inserting and reenabling foreign keys after insert.

And if You prefer using lookups/joins and You are using the same lookup in multiple dataflows, consider caching those lookups.